# Size of allocated buffer for argv in C Command line argument

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, argv, argc

When we write a C program that can take command line arguments, we write the main function as:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
. . .
}
```

We know `argc` is greater than equal to 1
So, at least `argv[0]` exists.
My question is what is size of allocated buffer for `argv[0]` and subsequent arguments, if any e.g. `argv[1]`, `argv[2]` etc?

Comment: I think this depends on implementation (I don't think there is a defined standard). I would expect most implementations to allocate just enough memory to fit each string (probably using strdup)

Answer (score 2):

> *We know argc is greater than equal to 1*

Well, that's not true. It shall be non-negative. It can be 0, also.

In case, `argv[n]` exists, the size of the `argv[n]` is the size of a pointer in your platform. The size of the memory pointed by the pointer is the same as the supplied command line arguments string (as suppiled by the underlying environment).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §5.1.2.2.1

> - The value of argc shall be nonnegative.

and,

> - If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through
>     `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given
>     implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup. The
>     intent is to supply to the program information determined prior to program startup
>     from elsewhere in the hosted environment. [...]
> - If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]`
>     represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the
>     program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of argc is
>     greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]`
>     represent the *program parameters*.

Comment: When it can be zero?

Comment: @purec it will be zero if the
program name is not available from the host environment and there is no program parameters.

Comment: `0` is also possible on a recursive call to `main()` - even though such a call is often problematic.

Answer (score 1):

> what is size of allocated buffer for `argv[0]` and subsequent arguments

The answer is "at least big enough to contain the string pointed at including the null terminator".

For example, on a typical Unix system, with the command

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

`argc` will be two and the buffer allocated to `argv[0]` will be at least 4 bytes and the buffer allocated to `argv[1]` will be at least 12 bytes. You cannot assume anything else about the sizes of the buffers or how and where they are allocated. That's all taken care of by the prelude code that runs before `main`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the full answer is, as said in a comment: it is platform-dependent.

But seems by looking at the source code that at least linux kernel will copy only the necessary bytes to the program stack.

Then there's also no guarantee that your compiler will not do some own magic to the arguments.